# How To Change Time Machine Password - Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, disk-utility, encryption

**How may a Solid-state drive (SSD) Time Machine backup password be changed for a SSD formatted as "Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)"?**

## Expected

This is how a Time Machine backup password is changed for an SSD formatted as "APFS (Case-sensitive, Encrypted)".

*APFS (Case-sensitive, Encrypted)*

1. Open *Disk Utility* app > Select the drive under the *External* category.
2. Select in the menu bar *File* > *Change Password...*

[image: Change Password]

*APFS Volume*

[image: APFS Volume]

## Observed

The *Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)* formatted SSD has the option for *Change Password...* grayed out.

[image: Change password grayed out]

*Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)*

[image: Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)]

Comment: See here for [How to change the Time Machine password from the Terminal command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/434140/164512)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the Time Machine app has removed the option to deselect encrypt backups, and then reselect the option in order to change the password.

To change a password you can use the Mac *Disk Utility* which comes with all macOS operating systems.

1. Open the *Disk Utility* app
2. *File* > *Change Password...* (This option is available for APFS formatted drives)
3. If *File* > *Change Password...* is grayed out.

   a. Erase the drive used for Time Machine backups

   b. Create a new drive

   c. Set a new password in the *Time Machine* app by selecting the encrypt option.

Answer (score 1):

## Remove and Re-Enable the Backup Drive from Time Machine With New Password

1. Open *System Preferences* > *Time Machine*
2. Remove current disk: *Select Disk...* > Under *Backup Disks*, choose the existing drive > *Remove Disk*

[image: Remove Disk]

3. Re-enable disk without the existing password: Select *Backup Disk...* > Select disk > Deselect *Encrypt backups* > *Use Disk*

[image: Deselect Encrypt backups]

4. Cancel the disk backup in-progress > Wait for the disk to decrypt
5. Repeat *Step 2*.
6. Re-enable disk with a new password: *Select Backup Disk...* > Select disk > Select *Encrypt backups* > *Use Disk*

Comment: In Ventura the interface no longer looks anything like this.

Comment: I've updated the answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/461544/304630).

Comment: I would add a comment saying that this particular solution works up to certain version of MacOS